# How to hide journal [OK] [FAILED] at start?

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster

I just want get rid of the scrolling journal at boot, the one that show if something failed.
I known that something went wrong at boot but indeed everything work fine on raspbian buster.

[image: journal [OK] [FAILED]]

Thx,

Ben

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just append to `/boot/cmdline.txt`

```
quiet plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

This should suppress all console output and only present you the login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up masking plymouth as a service.

```
sudo systemctl mask plymouth-start.service
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.